# Error retrieving data from backend server on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, express, netlify, netlify-function, netlify-cli

I have a Netlify project running which contains two git submodules.
Module 1 is a frontend server running on React.
Module 2 is an Express server that retrieves data and returns it.
I am now trying to fetch a URL in order to retrieve the correct data from the backend server.
But unfortunately I am getting this error: 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'.

The only line in my _redirects file (located in public folder of frontend server) is now:
/* /index.html 200

I have a proxy set to http://localhost:4000 (backend server) in the package.json of the frontend server.

Can someone tell me where the problem lays?

**Backend Server**
[image]

**Router in the backend server**
[image]

**Trying to fetch data like this**

This happens on the frontend server running on port 3000.
[image]

Comment: You need to post some code.  A minimal reproducible example would be good, to better allow people to help!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MattMorgan hopefully my screenshots give you more information